# Downgrading Minimum API version?

Tags: android, xamarin.android

I am having problem pushing my build to Google's Play Store.

I suspect the recent lowering the minimum version from 23 to 22. I have published quite a number of beta releases (no prod release yet).

Is it possible to lower the minimum API version after we publish a beta release?

How do I invalidate all the beta releases?

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to lower the minimum API version after we publish a beta release?

You need to change the minimum API version in the `AndroidManifest.xml` and update the apk to Google Play Store.

You could refer to [this article](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/113476?hl=en) for how to update the apk.